# How do I count a count?

Tags: sql-server

```
select top 10 sc.Site_Desc, count(pm.Site_Code) as Total
from (Primary_Summary pm 
inner join Site_Codes sc on sc.Site_Code = pm.Site_Code 
left outer join Diagnosis d on pm.CID = d.CID 
left outer join Outcomes o on pm.CID = o.CID) where pm.CID 
IN(select distinct CID from Syslists where label = '2011 don test')
group by pm.Site_Code, sc.Site_Desc
order by Total desc
```

That is my query I need to count the total that is coming back from Total. I'm blaming this on Friday and I'm brain is done.

Comment: `select sum(total) from (select top 10 ...) tmp_alias`

Comment: [@@RowCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)?